# Count words from list and save them and their count in a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, word-count

I have a `List` instance called `words` and a `HashMap` instance called `map`. I have certain words on the list and count them to save on the `HashMap`. The `HashMap` has count as value and word as key.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**IS THERE A BETTER IMPLEMENTATION FOR THIS?**

```
for (String aword : words) {
            map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            if (map.containsKey(aword)) {
                int count;
                try {
                    count = map.get(aword);
                    count++;
                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                map.put(aword, count);
                System.out.println(aword+"SS"+count);
            } else {
                map.put(aword, 0);
                System.out.println(aword+"else"+0);
            }
        }
```

My `else` clause is always entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new map in each iteration. You should move the map initialization to before the loop.

Comment: @Nabin well, I don't see why you need to catch NullPointerException, since you check for existence before getting the count from the map.

Comment: Anything else? Is this the best code to do the job? Efficient?

Comment: @Nabin looks decent, except one change you need,  init the count to 1, not 0, when the word is not found.

Comment: Thank you. I already spotted it once i could run the code Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats because you instantiate a new HashMap for every word:

```
for (String aword : words) {
    map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    // <- here
...
```

Move that out of the loop:

```
map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String aword : words) {
    if (map.containsKey(aword)) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Create map outside the for loop

```
map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String aword : words) {         
            if (map.containsKey(aword)) {
                int count;
                try {
                    count = map.get(aword);
                    count++;
                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                map.put(aword, count);
                System.out.println(aword+"SS"+count);
            } else {
                map.put(aword, 0);
                System.out.println(aword+"else"+0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using containsKey then get then put I do that :

```
    map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //put it here instead than in the for loop
    for (String aword : words) {
        Integer tmp = stats.put(word, 1); //tmp is the previous value associated with key "word"
        if (tmp != null) {
            stats.put(word, ++tmp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Nabin I guess it's the shorter and more efficient way to do it because you avoid to iterate over the map to much.

Answer (score 1):

Create the map outside the loop and remove the try-catch.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : words) {
        int count = map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) : 0;
        map.put(word, count + 1);
    }
```